# Applications crash when automated by a ui automation

Tags: python, ui-automation, microsoft-ui-automation

I am automating an application with python using the [uiautomation library](https://github.com/yinkaisheng/Python-UIAutomation-for-Windows). En python 3.6.8

I can access any element of the application without problems when I use the method

```
control = auto.ControlFromCursor ()
print (control.AutomationId, control.Name)
```

but when I try to create the element based on its properties, the application breaks

```
control = auto.Control(AutomationId=id_, Name=name, ClassName=cls_name)
```

even if I do this it fails

```
control = auto.ControlFromCursor ()
print (control.AutomationId, control.Name)
id_ = control.AutomationId
name = control.Name
cls_name = control.ClassName 
control = auto.Control(AutomationId=id_, Name=name, ClassName=cls_name)
```

I found this, from Microsoft but I don't know where to find those hotfixes or what I should do. Any ideas? :/

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/applications-crash-when-automated-by-a-ui-automation-client-app-in-windows-b746d17a-fda1-a1a2-9290-431fa155e859

This is the error

[image]

Comment: You're using [this library](https://github.com/yinkaisheng/Python-UIAutomation-for-Windows)? Did you read the part `Do not use 3.7.6 and 3.8.1, comtypes doesn't work in these two versions. Install an earlier version or the latest version.`? Are you sure your Python version isn't one of those? It'd be helpful if you shared your Python version.

Comment: @RandomDavis, Yes, I use that library. I use python 3.6.8. I have not had problems with the lib, I have automated about 10 different applications but with this application it fails :(

Comment: Well if nobody can figure out or solve the issue, then maybe you'll have to use another library, like [PyAutoGUI](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/).

Comment: What version of Windows are you using?  The hotfixes in question are only for Windows 8/Server 2012, which is long out of support.